# ASP.NET Core 6 - OData 8 - AutoExpand properties of type in controller

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I would like to be able to `AutoExpand` some properties conditionally.

For example,

```
public class InterlocutorDto 
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsPhysicalPerson { get; set; }
    public String CompanyName { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public String Name { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public String Firstname { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public Boolean IsNewsletter { get; set; }
    public AddressFormDto LetterTitle { get; set; }
    public String Comments { get; set; } = String.Empty;
}
```

In this example it would be the `LetterTitle` property.

But I would like to `AutExpand` only in the case of `/odata/Interlocutors/{id}` (because I would like to always provide this property when directly asking for a resource that users know the id) and not when calling `/odata/Interlocutors?$queryOptions` (I let users choose when looking for lot of results if they want this property or not)

```
[HttpGet]
[HttpGet("$count")]
public IActionResult GetInterlocutors(ODataQueryOptions<InterlocutorDto> queryOptions) 
{...}
```

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[EnableQuery]
public async Task<ActionResult<InterlocutorDto>> GetInterlocutor(Int32 id)
{...}
```

I've tried to use a derived type

```
builder.EntitySet<InterlocutorDto>("Interlocutors");
builder.EntityType<SingleInterlocutorDto>().Expand(SelectExpandType.Automatic);
```

where `SingleInterlocutorDto` would be

```
[AutoExpand]
public class SingleInterlocutorDto : InterlocutorDto {}
```

and I've tried to modify the queryOptions but everything seems to be read-only.

Is there a way to have an Entity that doesn't AutoExpand it's properties in some case and AutoExpand some in other cases (of course, without asking the user to add `$expand=LetterTitle`

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Can you override some methods by deriving from EnableQueryAttribute to modify the query option for the request by adding the 'expandable' properties?

Comment: Maybe but it seems like a hack....  Don't we have a featured way to do that ?

Comment: OData has [AutoExpand] attribute that you can put on properties

Comment: Thanks @SamXu, but it seems that you didn't really read my question. I already use the AutoExtandAttribute. What i would like it's either to condionnaly apply it, or to be able to change which properties have it depending on the case without having to need to ask the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found two ways to do this:

## 1. Middleware Filter

This method is hacky, but quick, and simple.

```cs
 public class ODataExpandFilter
 {

    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ErrorHandler _errorHandler;

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("odata/Interlocutors/") 
        {
            // may need to narrow down the match depending on your route layout
            var queryString = WebUtility.UrlDecode(context.Request.QueryString.Value);
            if (!queryString.Contains("$expand", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                // if manually expanding something, then don't add the auto expansion
                context.Request.QueryString = new QueryString(queryString + "&$expand=LetterTitle");
            }
        }
        await _next(context);
    }


    public ODataExpandFilter(RequestDelegate next, ErrorHandler errorHandler)
    {
        _next = next;
        _errorHandler = errorHandler;
    }
 }
```

then just adding this with

```cs
app.UseMiddleware<ODataExpandFilter>();
```

it will run before the OData handlers get to it.

## 2. queryoption manipulation

This method manipulates the queryoptions for the individual query, but it does seem to work.

```cs
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[EnableQuery]
public async Task<ActionResult<InterlocutorDto>> GetInterlocutor(Int32 id, ODataQueryOptions<InterlocutorDto> queryOptions)
{
    // build query as you need to from your dataset...

     var selectExpand = (queryOptions.SelectExpand == null ? 
                                    "LetterTitle" : 
                                    queryOptions.SelectExpand.SelectExpandClause.SelectedItems.Select(x => x.ToString()).Append("LetterTitle").Join(","));

    var expandOptions = new SelectExpandQueryOption(null, "LetterTitle", queryOptions.Context, new ODataQueryOptionParser(
                    model: queryOptions.Context.Model,
                    targetEdmType: queryOptions.Context.NavigationSource.EntityType(),
                    targetNavigationSource: queryOptions.Context.NavigationSource,
                    queryOptions: new Dictionary<string, string> { { "$expand", selectExpand } },
                    container: queryOptions.Context.RequestContainer));
                    queryOptions.Request.ODataFeature().SelectExpandClause = expandOptions.SelectExpandClause;

 IQueryable results = queryOptions.ApplyTo(query.AsQueryable());

  return IQueryable<InterlocutorDto>;
}
```

Comment: I really don't like this option but i came with the same answer as you !